# How to get rid of html tags in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

I need to get rid of the tags. The resulting `text1` variable should be equal to just one word : `Test` . Here is what I tried. Why doesn't my PERL regex work ?

```
data t;
text1="<html> <head> <meta name=''generator'' content=''HTML Tidy, see www.w3.org'' />
<title></title> </head> <body> <p>Test</p> <p></p> <table style=''WIDTH: 
360.0pt;BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse;'' border=''0'' cellspacing=''0'' cellpadding=''0'' width=''480''>"
;
regex = prxparse('s/<\s+.*?>/ /');
call prxchange(regex,-1,text1);
put text1;
run;
```

---

**I need to get rid of ANYTHING that is in between `<` and `>` and end up with a plain text**

Comment: Always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with SAS.  Also, regex processing of HTML is problematic.  For example, using the one that SzG recommends will work but you'll end up with the CSS stylesheet info, JavaScript, the title, etc.  Do you want all of that, or just the plain text in the body?

Comment: Oh wait, you're calling a perl regex in SAS?  My questions above still stand, but in this case your regex is looking for at least on space inside the brackets, and then text, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: @MauriceReeves Very good point. The regex approach works with this particular string. Who knows what happens with other html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have \s+ in there?

```
data t;
text1="<html> <head> <meta name=''generator'' content=''HTML Tidy, see www.w3.org'' />
<title></title> </head> <body> <p>Test</p> <p></p> <table style=''WIDTH: 
360.0pt;BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse;'' border=''0'' cellspacing=''0'' cellpadding=''0'' width=''480''>"
;
regex = prxparse('s/<.*?>/ /');
call prxchange(regex,-1,text1);
put text1;
run;
```

That works as expected.  It's not going to work for an awful lot of things, but it will work for the example case.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten the sigils from the beginning of all variables. It's `$text1`, not `text1`.

```
$text1 =~ s/<.+?>//g;
```

But this will still leave all the whitespace in the string. I don't know whether that's OK.

If the code happens to be not Perl, well...